# Opening external site in new tab/window and passing data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, cross-domain

I have a website (built on `ASP.NET` and `jQuery`)

There is a requirement to present the user with a link that will open an external site in a new window and pass data so that the external site can pre-populate some fields (the external site is built and maintained by a different company and on a different domain)

Is the only option available to us to pass the data the `queryString`? As the site is external, could I use a `form` element on my page and submit? There will be several pieces of data to pass and I am worried about the queryString length being an issue - what is the best way of opening the new site AND sending data?

Currently the data is not sensitive but encoding/encrypting could become a requirement further down the line

Comment: Depending on the external site, you could make a POST request which updates the external site data, then you can open the window with the external site link (which will show the data sent with the POST request).

Comment: If you send via HTTPS the query straing will be encrypted in transit. What happens once on the 3rd party site is up to them.

Comment: If the data is too large for a querystring. I would go with a POST, like Omar suggest. But instead of updating the external site, it could just render the page with the fields pre-populated. And add https to keep the data confidential.

Comment: @HansKilian - how would I render the page with the fields pre-populated? That is exactly what I want to do

Comment: You need to change the external system to do that, I think. Due to security issues, I would imagine browsers wouldn't let you change the other site from your site. Imagine if you could load Facebook and pre-populate the fields with a story about what a great guy Mike is...